# Haskell read from process

Tags: shell, haskell, process, io

I'm not quite sure where the problem is, so I'm uncertain if the title is really accurate. I want to open a shell process, and write to it then read the output:

```
import System.IO (hPutStr, hGetContents, hSetBuffering, hClose,
            BufferMode(NoBuffering))
import System.Process (runInteractiveProcess)

main = do
        (hIn, hOut, _, _) <- runInteractiveProcess
                                "/bin/sh" [] Nothing Nothing
        hSetBuffering hIn NoBuffering
        hPutStr hIn "ls /\n"
        hGetContents hOut >>= putStrLn
        hClose hIn
        hClose hOut
```

This seems to work (sort of):

```
$ ./mwe
bin
boot
cdrom
dev
etc
...
```

The problem is, the program hangs (I need to kill it with Ctrl-C). I suppose the shell is still running, which prevents the Haskell prohramfrom exiting. So I tried to terminate the shell explicitly with `terminateProcess`:

```
main = do
        (hIn, hOut, _, sh) <- runInteractiveProcess
                                "/bin/sh" [] Nothing Nothing
        hSetBuffering hIn NoBuffering
        hPutStr hIn "ls /\n"
        hGetContents hOut >>= putStrLn
        terminateProcess sh
        hClose hIn
        hClose hOut
```

but to no avail. I also tried to send `exit` to the shell:

```
    ...
    hGetContents hOut >>= putStrLn
    hPutStr hIn "exit\n"
    ...
```

which does not work either.

I'm sure the solution is embarrassingly simple, but I couldn't find it (tried searching for "haskell kill process", among others , but perhaps the problem is not what I think). Apologies in advance if this has been asked already. Any help much appreciated!

Comment: Your method is bad because you don't know when to stop reading and start sending more commands. A human shell user knows that because he sees the prompt. Your program has no idea where `ls` output ends and the prompt starts. You can in principle parse the output and detect the prompt but it is very hard and error-prone. Better organize it in such a way that you only run one command that first reads all the input and then produces all the output, and does not require any input in the middle of its output. The language you use is irrelevant.

Comment: Having said that, you can try sending `"ls\nexit\n"` first and then read the output. But it's easier to just execute `ls` directly with no shell at all.

Comment: I see. I was hoping (mistakenly, as it turns out) that disabling buffering would help with that, but I should have seen that it wouldn't (how can the program know when the shell is done writing?). The thing is, I was hoping to write to and read from the same shell several times, not launch a new shell for each command, in order to keep the same environment.  Anyway, thanks very much.

Comment: You should create another question with more details about your use case and why it's important to keep the same environment. Perhaps you'll get some ideas of alternative approaches to the problem. And then post a link to the new question in the comments here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have a bit of haskell code that reads content from a shell process, and it doesn't hang.... Give it a shot:

```
import System.Process
import GHC.IO.Handle.Text

main :: IO ()
main = do
   (_,Just ho1, _, hp1) <- createProcess (shell "find -iname \"*.lhs\""){std_out=CreatePipe}
   sOut <- hGetContents ho1
   _ <- waitForProcess hp1
```

Then, `sOut` will have the content of the shell process

Comment: Indeed , this does not hang. But I was wondering if I could create a process that I could keep around and pass to other functions, which would themselves write to and read from it. As @n.m. pointed out however, this wouldn't work. Thanks all the same.